# Facebook App Review - determinate where permission is used

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have built a facebook app a couple of months ago and recently it started using the permission `business_management`.

I would like to know where this permission is used because the app never uses the endpoints `/business`, `/business-user` and `/business-role-request` as described here: [business_management](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/business_management/)

My app uses the following endpoints:

- `/accounts` with the `fields` `id`, `access_token` and `name`
- `/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token` to receive long lived access token
- `/{pageid}/posts` with the fields `message`, `updated_time`, `created_time`, `permalink_url`, `full_picture` and `message_tags`

And thats it. There is no use of `business_management`. Is there a possibility to check where the endpoint is called?

I'm using graph api v6.0

Comment: What do you mean, _"and recently it started using the permission business_management"_? Apps don't start using permissions by themselves. Either you are asking your app users for that permission when they log in - or you don't.

Comment: Did you perhaps do some testing in Graph API Explorer, using this app id? If you requested the permission there once to test something, that might be enough to have it show up in the list of permissions "used" by the app.